# Slow query using aggregation framework mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I came up with this code to query a list of questions from db

```
question
    .aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "answers",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "questionID",
          as: "answersArray",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$answersArray",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "sign-ups",
          localField: "answersArray.profileID",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "answersArray.profileID",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$answersArray.profileID",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          answersArray: {
            $push: "$answersArray",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "questions",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "questionDetails",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$questionDetails",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          "questionDetails.answersArray": "$answersArray",
        },
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: "$questionDetails",
        },
      },
      { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    ])
```

And my questions schema:

```
let questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    question : {type: String, require: true},
    question_link : {type: String},
    category : {type: String, require: true},
    userID : {type: String , require: true},
    dateTime : {type: String,require: true},
    likes : {type: Array},
    totalAnswers : {type: Number, default: 0},
})
```

What's happening here is, look in db for all questions, using foreign key relation find answers for that particular question and append it in the questions object as "answersArray". After that in every answer that's associated with a particular question populate the field profileID.

Result looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "620b8180e2772e1b88b499e8",
    "question": "what is going on ?",
    "answersArray": [
      {
        "_id": "620b8180e2772e1b88b499k6",
        "answer": "it's going..",
        "questionId": "620b8180e2772e1b88b499e8",
        "userId": "620b8180e2772e1b88b499d48",
        "profileID" : {
          "_id": "620b8180e2772e1b88b499d4",
          "email": "abc@xyz.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**The actual question:**

It works perfectly but I feel like I've overdone stuff and in the Chrome debug section I see this query takes about 2.5 sec on average.
[image]
right now the data is about 200 doc's including questions and answers
I am new to MongoDB this is the best I could come up with so I want to know how I can improve this

Answer (score 0):

Few alterations are done to the pipeline

- Moved `$sort` as the 1st stage
- Since you need `question` field in the output, included that in the `$group` stage. And, in the process can strike-off the 4 stages (`$lookup` back to `question` collection, `$unwind`, `$addFields` to add back the `answersArray`, and `$replaceRoot`)

Altered Pipeline

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $sort: { _id: -1 }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "answers",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "questionID",
            as: "answersArray",
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$answersArray",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "sign-ups",
            localField: "answersArray.profileID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "answersArray.profileID",
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$answersArray.profileID",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            question: { $first: '$question' },
            answersArray: {
                $push: "$answersArray",
            }
        }
    }
]
```